# How close an Internet Explorer window, without the previously open disappear

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

Create the Internet Explorer instance:

```
            dynamic ie = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application"));

            ie.AddressBar = false;
            ie.MenuBar = false;
            ie.ToolBar = false;
            ie.Visible = true;
            ie.Navigate(@"C:\VirtualKeyboard\virtualkeyboard.html");
```

When I try to close the window:

```
ie.Quit();
```

The instance disappear from Task Manager Applications tab, but remains on the Processes tab.
I tried the following code:

```
                uint processid = 0;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr)hWnd, out processid);
                Process pro = Process.GetProcessById((int)processid);
                pro.CloseMainWindow();
                pro.WaitForExit(1000);

                if (!pro.HasExited)
                {
                    pro.Kill();
                }
```

With this code the instance is no longer on Processes tab, but makes the remaining instances disappear despite its processes remain.
I used the Spy++ and discover that the ProcessId it's the same. On the Task Manger the ProcessId are different.

Comment: Please try to avoid double negatives. They don't not hurt my brain

Comment: Sorry english it's not my first language

Comment: Why do you mind the remaining process?

Comment: I need to launch the same process more times